# how to create a method to take String parameter to specify the name of sth

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, methods, parameters

tutor asked us

how to create a new method called `addAlien` which takes a `String` parameter to specify the name of the alien, and create a new Alien object inside the method and then add it to the `ArrayList`.

I just wrote:

```
public void addAlien(String name)    
{
    Alien name = new Alien() 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope you are looking for:

```
ArrayList<Alien> list = new ArrayList<>();
public void addAlien(String name) {
    list.add(new Alien(name));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your addAlien method, the input parameter is bound to identifier 'name', as you declared:

```
public void addAlien(String name)  ...
```

so when the user pass in the string to the method, the string can be referred by the identifier 'name' and further use for other purpose. 
But right after that you created a variable of type Alien using the very same identifier (namely 'name'). This confusion should be cleared before looking into further development.

so instead of

```
Alien name = new Alien()
```

you should do

```
Alien newlyCreatedAlien = new Alien()
```

Notice it is syntactically legal to compile the code you wrote, it is a concept called "shadowing". Let me know if you have difficulties understanding or finding related material.

Finally, the string given by method user (now stored and referable by the identifier 'name') should be used right!
In this case, we are creating (constructing) a new Alien object. Typically, we invoke what is called 'constructor' of a class.

```
new Alien(someParameterPassedToTheConstructor)
```

the information stored in 'name' should therefore be passed via the parameter of constructor to create a specific Alien.

```
new Alien(name)
```

would be the trivial solution to the need.

Notice in the solution provided by DhiwaTdG, the newly created Alien is not stored using any identifier (it is created and then directly added to the list). It is perfectly fine since this method does not required to perform further operations on this particular Alien other then add it into the list. It is the list we're after, not the Alien (at least in this method).

Hope this would helped you clearing up some confusions.

Answer (score 0):

This should be helpful.

```
List<Alien> list = new ArrayList<>();

public void addAlien(String name) {
    list.add(new Alien(name));
}

class Alien{
    String name;
    public Alien(String name){
        this.name = name
    }
}
```